# Symfony Formbuilder selectbox with list of valid dates

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I have a simple entity with 3 fields validFrom (date), validTo (date) and price (integer).

Now I need an form, where validFrom is a date, but validTo should be a choice list of predefined dates. For prefining these dates I also have a model class.

```
class WeekCollection {

private $weeks;

/**
 * @param \DateTime $weekDate
 */
public function addWeek(\DateTime $weekDate)
{
    $this->weeks[] = $weekDate;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $weekDate
 */
public function removeWeek(\DateTime $weekDate)
{
    $pos = array_search($weekDate, $this->weeks);
    unset($this->weeks[$pos]);
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getWeeks()
{
    return $this->weeks;
}

}
```

My formbuilder looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) 
{
  $builder
        ->add('validFrom','date', array(
            'label' => 'Valid From',
            'data' => $options['checkin_date'],
            'read_only' => true,
            'widget' => 'single_text'
        ))
        ->add('myWeeks','choice', array(
            'choices' => $this->getWeeksFromModel(),
            'property_path' => 'validTo'
        ))
}

private function getWeeksFromModel()
{
    $weeks = new WeekCollection();
    $weeks->addWeek(new \DateTime());
    $weeks->addWeek(...some more dates...);
    $weeks->addWeek(...some more dates...);

    return $weeks->getWeeks();
}
```

I'm getting the error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\SimpleChoiceList::__construct() must be of the type array, object given

I understand that, but how can I use my collection of weeks as an input-select (which also should be mapped to validTo of my entity)?

Comment: Why can't you just transform the instantiation and adding to the `WeekCollection` to an array? What does `WeekCollection` offer that an array can not?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony wants an associative array like this:

```
$builder->add('myWeeks','choice', array(
        'choices' => array ('key1' => new \DateTime(),
                            'key2' => some other date,
                            'key3' => some other date)
        'property_path' => 'validTo'))
```

You have to modify your method getWeeksFromModel() in the right way.